# JDOM parser inserting  #FIXED manual attributes

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have issue with:

When I'm using org.jdom parser to build xml from exciting source, it's inserting manual attributes with values which were marked as #**FIXED** in DTD file, but in the source xml these attributes are not specified.

How can I prevent it from inserting these default #**FIXED** values into xml?
Ex:
Source XML

```
<head type="myhead">my table</head>
```

Result XML after DOM parser:

```
<head type="myhead" is-search="true">my table</head>
```

As you can see, `is-search` attribute is missing :(

**Resolved:**
added this lines

```
setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/validation", false);
setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-dtd-grammar", false);
setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);
```

Comment: What you tried ?Add some relevant code here...